# How to ignore # in awk script

Tags: linux, awk

I have an awk script that turns a config file into a csv. I am trying to ignore lines that start with #. Would I have to use \#?

This is my script

```
#!/bin/awk -f

# the line doesn't container "#" or "]" or "[" go here
$0 ~ /(#|\[|\])/ {
    # $1 $2        $3                            $4 $5 
    # 017 : Maximum_Plug_Speed                    = 75
    
    # config_name, option_number, option_value, NULL, NULL, NULL
    printf "%s\b\b\b\b,%s,%s,,,", FILENAME, $1, $5
}

# the line doesn't contain # and contains "[" or "]" got here
$0 ~ /[^#]/ && /([|])/ {
    # $1 $2        $3                            $4 $5             $6  $7 $8  $9
    # 019 * Overspeed_Limit_Set_Point             = 73              R [50 73] MPH

    # config_name, option_number, option_value, option_range_def, option_range_low, option_range_high  
    printf "%s\b\b\b\b,%s,%s,%s%s%s%s,$s,$s", FILENAME, $1, $5, $6,  $7, $8, $9, substr($7,1), $8
}
```

Is this right?

Comment: Why not just write a line of code and see if you need to escape `#` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily skip lines that start with `'#'` or have their first non-whitespace character as `'#'` by writing a rule to skip to the `next` line. You can include as your first rule:

```
/^ *#/ {next}
```

Which will do what you need.

**Explanation of the REGEX**

- `/^ *#/` - match at `^` the beginning of the line zero or more  whitespace characters  `*` (`space*`) followed by a `'#'`

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '/^ *#/ {next}1' << eof
> # my dog
> has fleas
>    # my cat
> has none
> eof
has fleas
has none
```

(the `1` in the example above is just shorthand for the default `print` operation)

---

**Skipping Additional Characters**

If you really do want to skip all lines that contain `'#'` or `'['` or `']'`, (as shown as the first comment in your script) then you can add `(ex1|exp2|exp3)` where expressions `exp1..3` are optionally matched regular expressions. You will need to escape `\[` and `\]` as both `'['` and `']'` have special meaning as part of a character class, e.g.

```
/(^ *#|\[|\])/ {next}
```

That will skip lines with `'#'` as the first non-whitespace character or `'['` or `']'` anywhere in the line.

**Example**

```
$ awk '/(^ *#|\[|\])/ {next}1' << eof
> # my dog
> has [fleas
>    # my cat
> ]has none
> lucky cat!
> eof
lucky cat!
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13. Glad to see you about tonight!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if line does contain certain character and do not want to care about escpaing you might exploit `index` function, which is one of [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html). It does return position of said character if it was found else `0`, thus if you use that as condition it would be met if character was found anywhere.

For example `print`ing all lines which contain `[` might be done via

```
awk 'index($0,"["){print}' file.txt
```